# QDebug's operator<< chained output,including include expression,output unexpected result

Tags: qt

When I execute following code:

```
bool ok = false;
QByteArray ba("fffff3");
qDebug() << ok << ba.toInt(&ok, 16) << ok;
```

The output is **true 16777203 true**,I vaguely know why.Someone can explain what is going on.What is **ok**'s change process?

Comment: You are surprised that you got `true` as first, that is because the order of evaluation is unspecified [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), so `toInt()` was invoked, `ok` was modified to true, and while printing results  you got `true` twice.

Comment: @rafix07 xiexie.